# Create standalone SVN server on an external hard disk

Tags: svn, server, external, portability

Does anyone know if there is a way to host a standalone SVN server on a portable hard disk drive?

What we want is to save specific files on the portable drive and find a way to create a stanadalone server so that anyone will be able to just connect the drive to his pc and start the server service from the drive without needing to install anything.

The reason we do not use a normal server is that we need to store and monitor large files (GBs in size) so if we store them on a remote repository, it will take forever to checkout and commit. Also, the reason we do not wish to create a local server on one of our laptops, that will be accessible within our network is that we need to make sure that the repository will be available all the time. So if we manage to have a portable SVN server on an external hard disk drive, anyone will be able to just plug it in his PC and run the server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say that the bandwidth is ~ 1MBit (~100kbytes/sec), I can guess that the approach you are thinking about can make sense. Setup `svnserve` on the USB stick and [run it as daemon](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.invoking.daemon) on any of the computers.

---

> Does anyone know if there is a way to host a standalone SVN server on
>   a portable hard disk drive?

If there is going to be only one user accessing the repository at a time, you don't even need any server at all. You can access Subversion repositories over file:// access scheme locally. No server is required in such case, but you are not able to configure repository hooks or security.

> it will take forever to checkout and commit.

Are you sure about this? Try the latest Subversion 1.9 server and client. E.g. try VisualSVN Server 3.5 with TortoiseSVN 1.9 or check the binary packages page: http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

Comment: When I say it will take forever, I mean if we use our company's online repository. Checkout or commit will be limited by our Internet connection speed which is significantly lower than the inter-company network's and I mentioned that I am talking about large repositories (up to 10 GBs). As for the first part of your answer, no, it won't be only one person accessing the repository at a time.

Comment: 1. "Up to 10GBs" is not that large for Subversion. 2. simultaneous access over file:// by multiple users is not recommended and may cause problems.

Comment: It is not large for subversion, I never said it is. I said it is pretty large for our internet connection speed, uploading a 10 GB file with an upload ratio of 100 KBs and even downloading with 1MBs, if my math is correct will need about 3 hours, which is way too high.

Comment: @A.Schoinas hmm. With such a low bandwidth it will take a considerable amount of time to upload new 10GB files to the repository. In such case, I'd setup `svnserve` on the USB stick and run it as daemon on any of the computers: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.invoking.daemon

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @A.Schoinas you are welcome! I've just updated the answer.

Comment: @bahrep Svn try to recalculate the file check sum for status operations. It's take a some time on v1.8 (few seconds for 1 GB per file). Is it improved in v1.9 ?